# Checking differentiabilty of complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The function $f$ is defined by
$$ f(z) = \begin{cases}
\frac{\bar{z}^2}{z},\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{ if }z\neq 0\\
0,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{ if }z=0\\
\end{cases}$$ 
Locate all the points z at which $f$ is complex differentiable, and determine $f'(z)$ for each such point.

so I first tried to find whether the Cauchy Riemann Condition I find out that $u_x=v_y$ gives $y=\pm x$ and $u_y=-v_x$ gives $y=\pm ix$.

Since $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, so it is differentiable nowhere.

Am I right? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y=\pm ix \,;\, x, y \in \mathbb R \mbox{ implies } x=y=0$$

This shows that $f$ can only be differentiable at $z=0$. To check differentiability here, use definition.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I was thinking that but the second condition just threw me off. I checked the differentiability and found out that it is differentiable and $f'(0)=0$. Am I right?

Comment: @mint nope, $f$ is not differentiable at $z=0$. Since the partial derivatives are not continuous, you cannot use Cauchy Riemann for differentiability, you must use the definition.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it now....

Answer (score 1):

To check at $z=0$, take $z$ along the line $t e^{i\theta}$ then
$\lim_{t \to 0} { f(t e^{i\theta}) - f(0) \over t e^{i\theta} } = e^{-i4\theta} $. It follows that $f$ is not differentiable at $z=0$.